# How to insert record in parent table and in Child table simultaneously ( child table adds details to the parent table)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

my aim was to create a connection between tables that could simulate inheritance.
I have a Parent table named  MultimediaResource with a PK named Resource_ID and a list of columns of description in common with all the resources. Then i have created child tables like "Movie", "Book" that use as a FK the Resource_ID and have columns to add details relative to the kind of table that they are (for ex: book has a column named NumberOfPages which in movie is not present). Is this a good practice to organize the tables like that to simulate inheritance?

And on to the question, how can i insert a record that puts values in both parent table and child table at the same time?

Im working with the JDBC

thank you!

Comment: You have to use multiple queries in one transaction

Comment: If you have a foreign key in child then the entry in parent has to exist before you can create the child..